# How to Change the Name of the Hyperlink?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

[image: Hyperlink]

The code below creates a hyperlink on the x's under # column, and when clicked arrives at the latest nonempty cell under the 2 PQ Columns (first x - > 'good' under 'Blah PQ19' column, 4th x -> 1 under 'Blah PQ18' column.)

I need to replace/rename the x's with either PQ18 or PQ19 (under where the hyperlink arrives to). I've attempted looking at posts to learn how to fetch the column header name and bring to change the x's but couldn't do it..
Does anyone know how to do this?

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim PCell As String

For i = 2 To 5

If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, "CT").End(xlToRight)) Then
PCell = Cells(i, "CT").End(xlToRight).Address
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(i, 2), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & Sheet1.Name & "'!" & PCell
End If

Next i
```

Comment: There is a TextToDisplay parameter in the Hyperlinks.Add method.

Comment: How do I display the column header's name where the hyperlinks land at..? For instance, rename first x to PQ19 and fourth x to PQ18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment you can look into the `TextToDisplay` parameter of the `Hyperlinks.Add` method:

---

***<sub>Sample data in Range(A1:F5):</sub>***

[image]

---

***<sub>Code:</sub>***

```
Sub Test()

Dim x As Long

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheets CodeName
    For x = 2 To 5
        i = .Cells(x, "CT").End(xlToLeft).Column 'Notice xlToLeft instead to Right
        If i > 1 Then
            .Hyperlinks.Add .Cells(x, 1), "", "'" & .Name & "'!" & .Cells(x, i).Address, , .Cells(1, i).Value
        End If
    Next x
End With

End Sub
```

---

***<sub>Result:</sub>***

[image]

Comment: There's an 'invalid or unqualified reference' error on .Cells  in i=… What is y for?

Comment: @cd3091, discard `y` variable. Was there by accident. Your error comes because your sheet's [`CodeName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.codename) is wrong. You can find the right value in your project explorer window.

Comment: How could your code be altered to apply for the bigger worksheet? The Cell "CT" was the column right before the one that I wanted to check for xlLeft. I want the latest column P that is nonempty. The problem is there are many repeating P,Q,R,S columns and only the nonempty on Column P matters. I want to post a new question but I am banned from it. I also want to say sorry if I misused your code in other post.

Comment: @cd3091, best is to go and revisit your questions and upvote/accept answer that have answered your questions to return the favor. Maybe this will lift your ban?

Comment: I did what you said, and it still says I've reached the limit to ask questions. Maybe it will take awhile. Do you have any suggestions for my last question?

Comment: Below is what I have to hyperlink a cell but the j part is not working/changing. Columns are of types A, B, C, A, B, C, .. and for j I'm trying to find the last B column that is nonempty. Can you help?  i = .Cells(x, "CT").End(xlToRight).Column If i > 1 Then .Hyperlinks.Add .Cells(x, 2), "", "'" & .Name & "'!" & .Cells(x, i).Address, , Right(Cells(1, i).Value, 4)      Exit For      End If
        j = .Cells(x, "CV").End(xlRight).Column
If j > 1 Then .Hyperlinks.Add .Cells(x, 3), "", "'" & .Name & "'!" & .Cells(x, j).Address, , Right(Cells(1, j).Value, 4) End If    Exit For

Comment: Types A,B,C, are just examples. Trying to hit the last cell in the type with nonempty value...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the value of the cell...

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim PCell As String

For i = 2 To 5

  If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, "CT").End(xlToRight)) Then
    PCell = Cells(i, "CT").End(xlToRight).Address
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(i, 2), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & Sheet1.Name & "'!" & PCell
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = "Test " & i ' not sure what you want to set it to?
  End If

Next
```

Comment: I want to set it to the column header's name where the hyperlinks arrive at, but I have no clue how to do that.. For instance, rename first x to PQ19 and fourth x to PQ18.

Comment: To set the header's name instead, change the `i` to a `1` on both lines.